# How can you run CakeChat on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, deployment

Im using Heroku and I would like to use [CakeChat](https://github.com/lukalabs/cakechat) on it. I would like to deploy the app using Github. How do you do that? It wont work for me, it says it cant find a c++ compiler.

This is the error code:

```
error: Command "gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.o -MMD -MF build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.o.d" failed with exit status 1
           ----------------------------------------
       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-81j2vsfm/numpy/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-81j2vsfm/numpy/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-9289t74f/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9/numpy Check the logs for full command output.
```

I got this error when I tried to fork the CakeChat repo and then deploy it.

Comment: Hi James and welcome to StackOverflow ! Could you please provide us more details like which steps of the deployment you already done and also paste us the error message ? For us to better understand. Thanks !